# Flutter WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://chatandcall.legalremit.xyz:0/ws/?EIO=4&transport=polling#' was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: flutter, websocket, socket.io, chat

I want to implement Chat functionality but I got the above error. My Chat API URL is working fine in React JS but it gives issues in the Flutter app.

I used **socket_io_client: ^2.0.3+1** for code implementation.

This is my implemented code

```
Socket socket = io(
        'https://chatandcall.legalremit.xyz',
        OptionBuilder()
            .setPath('/ws')
            .disableAutoConnect() // disable auto-connection
            .setExtraHeaders({
              'Connection': 'Upgrade',
              'Upgrade':'websocket',
              'Origin': 'https://chatandcall.legalremit.xyz'
            }) // optional
            // .setQuery({'token': "babaji"})
            .build());

    socket.connect();
```